# Is it possible to have your live sass compiler to read from multiple input source and compile into their respective output directories

Tags: sass

I am using django and I have this directory setup

```
/project
  /apps
  |  /app1
  |  |  /templates
  |  |    /app1
  |  |      app1.html
  |  |  /static
  |  |    /app1
  |  |      /css (desired)
  |  |        app1.css(desired)
  |  |      /scss
  |  |        _app1-partial.scss
  |  |      app1.scss
  |  /app2
  |    /templates
  |      /app2
  |        app2.html
  |    /static
  |      /app2
  |        /css (desired)
  |          app2.css(desired)
  |        /scss
  |          _app2-partial.scss
  |        app2.scss
  /templates
    base.html
    navbar.html
  /static
  |  /images
  |  /css (desired)
  |    style.css(desired)
  |  /scss
  |    _partial.scss
  |  style.scss
  /project
    settings.py
  manage.py
```

Is it possible that I can have a live sass compiler extension to compile multiple source scss inputs into multiple css output files?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had it figure it out but I appreciate corrections for me to learn.

This is what I had before

```
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "compressed",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/css",
      "savePathReplacementPairs": null
    }
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [
    "/static/*.scss",
    "/static/**/*.scss"
  ],
```

Changes I made

```
  "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [
    "/static/*.scss",           // for root static scss file
    "/apps/**/static/**/*.scss" // for app specific scss file
  ],
```